# ¿Cómo "traducir" una parte de codigo en c++ a java?

Tags: java, c++

No sé mucho de c++ por lo que se me está complicando pasarlo a java, tengo el siguiente fragmento de código en c++:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    int odd,even;
    int a[10000];
    while(t--)
    {
        odd=even=0;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
            if(a[i]%2==0)
                even++;
            else
                odd++;
        }
        if (odd & 1 or (odd > 0 and even > 0))
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión es que no entiendo como "traducir" esta parte del código a java:

```
   if (odd & 1 or (odd > 0 and even > 0))
                cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"NO"<<endl;
```

Les agradecería mucho si me ayudan ya que no conozco mucho el lenguaje de c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aun que java soporta operadores de bit de manera similar que C++, este ultimo tiena una particularidad el cual es que el valor 0 y 1 pueden ser representados como valores booleanos por lo cual esta instruccion **odd & 1  ||** no solamente esta aplicando el operador de bit llamado AND entre la variable odd y el numero 1 si no que ademas el resultado de esa operacion es usado  como valor de tipo booleano en cojunto con el operador **||** mejor conocido como **OR** logico dentro del if, lo mismo aplica para el resto de la operacion **(odd > 0 && even > 0)**.

Bueno aclarado esto te dejo la traduccion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int t, n;
    t = sc.nextInt();
    int odd, even;
    int a[] = new int[10000];
    while (t-- > 0) {
        odd = even = 0;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
                even++;
            else
                odd++;
        }
        boolean inst1 = odd > 0 && even > 0 ? true : false;
        boolean inst2 = (odd & 1) > 0 ? true : false;

        if (inst1 || (inst2)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda o cuestion dejalo en la caja de comentarios.
Saludos.

Comment: el principio de la traduccion si lo pude hacer pero lo ultimo se me complico, gracias, ya funciono correctamente

Answer (score -1):

Hace años que no veo c++, pero me atrevo a decir que básicamente  se traduce como:

```
if (odd & 1  || (odd > 0 && even > 0)){
    System.out.println("YES");
}else{
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

Siendo `odd & 1` una comparacion de `bit` a `bit` no creo que existe diferencia.

Los Operadores `and` y `or` se sobre entiende, aunque estos son `&&` y `||` respectivamente.

El `cout` equivale a un `System.out.print` de java, los operadores `<<`, son operadores de escritura.(Todo junto nos sirve para mostrar por consola).
En `C++` existen también operadores de lectura `>>`, que es algo parecido a un objeto `Scanner` de java.

Por ultimo `endl` que indica un salto de linea, razon por la cual en el ejemplo utilizo `System.out.println`.